# How to change cell width from List in JasperReports dynamically with Java API

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I cant find the right method to change the cell width  dynamically from a List in JasperReports.

```
final JasperDesign template = JRXmlLoader.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("report_tarif_comparison.jrxml"));
final JRBand[] bands = template.getAllBands();
final JRElement element = bands[1].getElementByKey("compareList");
```

I get the List by `getElementByKey`, but the element Object has no method such as `setCellWidth` or `setCellHeight`

Part of my jrxml file:

```
<jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal" ignoreWidth="false">
    <datasetRun subDataset="compareTarif" uuid="03bdfbc4-19ae-47a1-a27e-bbacde25965f">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{policies})]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:listContents height="494" width="138">
        ....//textfields
    </jr:listContents>
</jr:list>
```

In Jaspersoft Studio, I can change the Cell Width in the properties window from the List:

[image: Jasper Studio, Properties from List]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this:

```java
JRComponentElement element = (JRComponentElement) bands[1].getElementByKey("compareList");
ListComponent component = (ListComponent) element.getComponent();
DesignListContents contents = (DesignListContents) component.getContents();
contents.setWidth(...);
```

Note that this only change the width of the cell.  If you also want to make the text fields inside wider, you'll have to do it explicitly; you can get the elements via `contents.getElements()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help:). Finally, element has no method getComponent(). But i looped through bands[1].getChildren() and proof if the child is an instance of JRDesignComponentElement. Then i used the method getComponent().